# WordPress - How to change page title dynamically without affecting menu

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website. I am trying to change the page title dynamically based on the parameter passed in the url. I am using the the_title() hook, but it also changing the menu. I have also used the in_the_loop() method to prevent the menu change, but no luck. How to change page title dynamically without affecting menu? 
Here is my code:

```
add_filter('the_title','some_callback');
function some_callback($data){  
        global $post; 
    $new_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if($id != "" && in_the_loop())
    {   
       $banner = getbanner($id);
       if($banner == ""){return $post->post_title;}        
           else { return $post->post_title." $banner;   }  
    }
    else { return $post->post_title;  }  
}
```

Comment: I am thinking that your website has a menu. If you change the page_title, it also changes the menu label on the website. Is that correct?

Comment: yes correct, don't want to change menu

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to make the menu display?

Comment: actually I am using a theme

Answer (score 0):

Changing the title of a static page using a dynamic URL is bad practice and will hurt your SEO ratings. That said you can make sure the title of a page is not being taken from the page's title by going to Appearance->Menus and adding a Navigation Label to that page's menu item.